# How to create canvas animate on page scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, canvas

Please take a look at this site: https://www.town.shimane-misato.lg.jp/misatoto/.

When we scroll the page ,the background animation appears is on canvas. How to create such animation in canvas? Is it developed by some tool or using a JS library and how to create similar results.

I would appreciated if you can shed some light on this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a couple libraries you could use. Scrollmagic is the closest thing that matches your demo site from what I've seen so far.

https://scrollmagic.io/

https://michalsnik.github.io/aos/

Other libraries
https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/scrolling-effects-js-libraries/

Comment: Thanks. Using Scrollmagic we can have the control of user's scroll position. But how the canvas is created?